# RFC 8058 (email unsubscribe) custom implementation not working on gmail

Tags: gmail, email, rfc

Gmail suggest email lists to implement [RFC 8058](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8058): https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en

I'm just testing my implementation and Gmail didn't work for it - it didn't offer Unsubscribe button. Gmail is supposed to support https unsubscribe links.

These are the headers of the actual email from the production (most important parts are obvious List-Unsubscribe headers:

```
Delivered-To: mladen.adamovic@gmail.com
Received: by 10.25.77.213 with SMTP id a204csp615696lfb;
        Wed, 17 Jan 2018 08:01:53 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ACJfBotKb5S5lOTyV2frh5MfXo8dqqIZP5XuKlLAmUAOhQv+EGJZIyVnbRQbucG7DUprHbOO0XJE
X-Received: by 10.107.43.75 with SMTP id r72mr41615665ior.53.1516204913605;
        Wed, 17 Jan 2018 08:01:53 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1516204913; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=YEewevXkWAjpTWh8vOx9mbGK+4B9jplYXnR1qx3ikMQkuJa+9j5P4XZhQ9Fw6f3coP
         njnejTdNXPPIhW4R1bFF9ieBL6TkqYYAJfsK7gU1LU6I6ptX6g+d6Pu824liIolHUN+/
         wSRtngo/IWTIGSyjFl+jX4Y/1QbW5hgX9hC3daCgYvNNb34cP0x+K66h8ERcgLBVwUTw
         Rue1PloBRJHOJ5ZS2FZLwOKr6Fd26XOdQnYTSMkMamXaJWyhrY/6rhpoANQRgkVKvR2J
         wGy39KGbP3F/ZpB7dMJWnr9yoXTco4ludkgTNSeY/vr6HOBC289gVfuXb2TYFVF2j8Wk
         b/iQ==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=precedence:list-unsubscribe:list-unsubscribe-post
         :content-transfer-encoding:mime-version:subject:message-id:to:from
         :date:dkim-signature:arc-authentication-results;
        bh=x4OCbLBEbAy/0KQdfNvWKUdWX+IPtH2iPX4WQR49WpQ=;
        b=t4T6t8qtyAyHiNCsxr63n04z55AqAJvIqsf6Q7VLJhB7Ficp66zjwGKrkL8pX1xzoj
         YOyopq52uxehGSLgd51yGEEdCKM9doL9oj0ekfM+9RVsSZ3lj/VVb+llAhr9IsJboEMR
         4TE/eDhdfgUsI74UMiHkv+nqqlAwYgdxUPW73CWRttBUR1BMp62KyJSxh6sav3M8fOe1
         fp6Hr1Fs0mlDKzSt90b/JeF4tys+Ks6q/t9BisgtbVV0A1LzRCjOrBvRpezXfLML6cTn
         mgbEW+Xllvc+jWrg+yRBUbkbxMIF+bWFdeIM8rkraaMSflIG0jhHRLERtOnO5m7HLMPH
         LrNA==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@numbeo.com header.s=mail header.b=X6ctVVah;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of noreply@numbeo.com designates 209.126.119.66 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=noreply@numbeo.com
Return-Path: <noreply@numbeo.com>
Received: from numbeo.com (numbeo.com. [209.126.119.66])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id v6si4439265iov.15.2018.01.17.08.01.53
        for <mladen.adamovic@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 17 Jan 2018 08:01:53 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of noreply@numbeo.com designates 209.126.119.66 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.126.119.66;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@numbeo.com header.s=mail header.b=X6ctVVah;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of noreply@numbeo.com designates 209.126.119.66 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=noreply@numbeo.com
Received: from condor1796.startdedicated.net (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by numbeo.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id A231540A0CF8 for <mladen.adamovic@gmail.com>; Wed, 17 Jan 2018 10:01:47 -0600 (CST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=numbeo.com; s=mail; t=1516204907; bh=x4OCbLBEbAy/0KQdfNvWKUdWX+IPtH2iPX4WQR49WpQ=; h=Date:From:To:Subject:List-Unsubscribe:From; b=X6ctVVah1BrjbaTF1YozYph8OvJaAIQB399y+iBgAx+QAnYkLbwQJkYx9Oz8ziK5R
     KznPL5UQmhfz22bHSagL90zQ/4bWBFUjY8+GK44OmjhVtFfBf/g/ZcwAh6sLn0IKv2
     HRVIzRw9BnLh64d5WnSGyATB5kHup65F9Hhkf/d4=
Date: Wed, 17 Jan 2018 10:01:47 -0600 (CST)
From: "Numbeo.com" <noreply@numbeo.com>
To: mladen.adamovic@gmail.com
Message-ID: <972498942.305.1516204907652@condor1796.startdedicated.net>
Subject: test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
List-Unsubscribe-Post: List-Unsubscribe=One-Click
List-Unsubscribe: <https://www.numbeo.com/common/unsubscribe.jsp?email_address=mladen.adamovic@gmail.com&key=key_ommitted>
Precedence: Bulk
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The question is rather old, but probably my hint will help someone else:
RFC 8058 mandates that the List-Unsubscribe-Post header must also be part of the DKIM signature. The mail headers above show that this is not the case in the example given by Mladen.

Comment: This is how DKIM is configured: https://mladenadamovic.wordpress.com/2018/01/17/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-ubuntu-xenial-16-04-lts/ is there a problem somewhere there?

Comment: Please have a look at the manpage of opendkim.conf describing the configuration item "SignHeaders". IMHO the header  "List-Unsubscribe-Post" is not a header which is signed by default. So you have to list it explicitly.

Comment: Why in that production email From is twice mentioned: Date:From:To:Subject:List-Unsubscribe:From ?

Comment: so if understand correctly 'SignHeaders             From,Sender,To,CC,Subject,Message-Id,Date,List-Unsubscribe,List-Unsubscribe-Post' in opendkim.conf should solve the problem?